# Esri Dojo component is unable to find div when placed inside polymer element

Tags: javascript, dojo, polymer, esri, web-component

While working on a Polymer website I wanted to encapsulate most of the functionality needed for ESRI's dojo-based map component so that I could reuse the code as a polymer component. I attempted to create the element using the code below, but the map constructor throws an error because it can't find a  with the id of 'map'.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/css/esri.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<polymer-element name="esri-map">
    <template>
        <style>
            #map {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: wheat;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="map" render=""></div>
    </template>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/"></script>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            ready: function () {
                var map;
                require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function (Map) {
                    map = new Map("map", {
                        basemap: "topo",
                        center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
                        zoom: 13
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

When the element is used the div is called and I can see it, but the following javascript error occurs:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

I don't know if anyone has experience trying to get these two technologies to play nice, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Including some code that shows how this should be done using the same `div id="map"` in the template body.

Note the difference is in how you find the element. You need to use `this.$.map` or `self.$.map` as below depending on the scope. I'm assuming you already have a fix for this though since you posted in Nov.

```
  Polymer({

            // Defaults here provide hints as to type for polymer
            basemap: null,
            extent: '-130,25,-65,50',
            wkId: 4326,
            map: null,
            ready: function(){
            },
            domReady: function() {
                var self = this;

                require(['esri/map',
                         'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
                         'esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer',
                         'esri/dijit/Popup',
                         'esri/dijit/PopupTemplate',
                         'esri/geometry/Extent',
                         'esri/SpatialReference',
                         'dojo/ready'],
                    function(Map,FeatureLayer,ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer,Popup,PopupTemplate,Extent,SpatialReference,ready){

                        var mapOptions = {
                            autoResize: true,
                            basemap: self.basemap,
                            sliderPosition: 'top-right'
                        };

                        if(self.extent){
                            var ext = self.extent.split(',');
                            mapOptions.extent = new Extent(+ext[0],+ext[1],+ext[2],+ext[3],new SpatialReference({wkid: self.wkId}));
                        }

                       self.popup = new Popup({
                        }, dojo.create("div"));

                        self.map = new Map(self.$.map, mapOptions);
```